# Django select option rest after error message appear in template if i change option in select

Tags: jquery, django

i have created form for delivery note, i am using form formset,

forms.py

```
  class Delivery_note_transiction_form(forms.Form):
        item = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=False,queryset=Product.objects.none(),widget=Select2Widget(attrs={"class" : "item"}))
        description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'placeholder' : 'optionall','class' : 'description'}),label=False,required=False)
        quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'quantity'}),label=False,min_value=0)
        id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,required=False)
```

views.py

```
def delivery_note_creation(request):
    Delivery_note_transiction_form_formset = forms.formset_factory(form=Delivery_note_transiction_form,can_delete=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_no = Invoice_max.objects.get(invoice_name='delivery')
        form = Deliver_Note_Main_Modelform(request.POST,initial={'delivery_invoice_no' : inv_no.invoice_no + 1})
        formset = Delivery_note_transiction_form_formset(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

            ins = form.save(commit=False)
            ins.author = request.user
            ins.save()

            for transfer in formset:
                Delivery_Note_Transiction.objects.create(item=transfer.cleaned_data['item'],
                                                         description=transfer.cleaned_data['description'],
                                                         quantity=transfer.cleaned_data['quantity'],
                                                         delivery_invoice_no=ins ,
                                                         )

            max_invoice = Invoice_max.objects.get(invoice_name='delivery')
            max_invoice.invoice_no = max_invoice.invoice_no + 1
            max_invoice.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('delivery note:delivery note home page'))

    else:
        invoice_create = Invoice_max.objects.get_or_create(invoice_name='delivery')
        inv = Invoice_max.objects.get(invoice_name='delivery')
        form = Deliver_Note_Main_Modelform(initial={ 'deliver_date' : datetime.today(), 'delivery_invoice_no' : inv.invoice_no + 1, 'total_quantity':0})
        formset = Delivery_note_transiction_form_formset()
    return render(request,'delivery_note/delivery note creation.html', { 'deliver_main': form,
                                                                         'delivery_transiction' : formset


       })
```

trmplate.html

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}

{% endblock title %}

{% block media %}
    {{ deliver_main.media.css }}
    {{ delivery_transiction.media.css}}
{% endblock media %}

{% block content %}


    <div class="w3-container">
        <h1>Delivery Note</h1>

        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                {{ deliver_main.errors }}
                {{ deliver_main.non_field_errors }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">{{ deliver_main.customer|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">{{ deliver_main.deliver_date|as_crispy_field }}</div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">{{ deliver_main.delivery_address|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">{{ deliver_main.delivery_invoice_no|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table class="w3-table-all w3-border w3-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-4">Item</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-4">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-4">Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                {{ delivery_transiction.management_form }}
                {% for error in delivery_transiction.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for error in delivery_transiction.non_form_errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}

                {% for delivery in delivery_transiction %}
                    <tr class=" delivery_form ">
                        {{ delivery.id }}
                        <td class="col-sm-4">{{ delivery.item|as_crispy_field  }}</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-4">{{ delivery.description|as_crispy_field  }}</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-4">{{ delivery.quantity|as_crispy_field  }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <button id="add-row" type="button">Add Row</button>
            <div class="row ">
                {{ deliver_main.description|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ deliver_main.total_quantity|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>


            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </div>





{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
    <script>
        $("#id_customer").change(function () {
            var url = "{% url "delivery note:product ajax" %}";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".item").html(data);

                    alert(data)
                }
            })
        })
    </script>

    <script>
        {#for set address in delivery#}
        $("#id_customer").change(function () {
            var customer = $("#id_customer option:selected").text();
            var url = "{% url 'saleinvoice:adress ajax' %}";

            {#for set address#}
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'customer': customer
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_delivery_address").text(data);
                }
            });
        });


        {#col total calculation#}
        $(document).on("change",".quantity", function () {
            colum_calculation(".delivery_form", ".quantity", "#id_total_quantity")
        })


    </script>



    <script>
        $("#add-row").click(function () {
            var url = "{% url 'delivery note:model add row' %}"
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                success : function (data) {
                    $(".delivery_form:last").after(data)
                    $(".django-select2").each(function () {
                        $(this).djangoSelect2()
                    })
                    last_formset_settings(".delivery_form", ".delivery_form:last", ".item", ".description", ".quantity")

                }

            })

        })

    </script>

{% endblock script %}


{% block end %}


    {{ deliver_main.media.js }}
    {{ delivery_transiction.media.js }}


{% endblock end %}
```

item select formset is render empty, so when user select some customer it will add optio, in items depending of which customer user select, code is working fine when user select cutomer option is added in items, but problem arises when , there is error happen in form and template  show error messaage, item which is aded using ajax when customer is change, item select reverse back to empty option which is asking for select itm

so i want a solution that item select option and user select item remain in item select even when , error message appear intemplate

Comment: What is the error

Comment: I have change option in item select using ajax when customer is selected, it is required to give value for quantity, so if user forget to enter quantity value it gives "value required in quantity error message" when this happen select option in item become none and if iuser selected item previously then it will also required to select again item